# End Recurring Job after ‘n’ times execute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I'm using Hangfire version "1.6.8".

```
var datetime = DateTime.Now; 

var cron = Cron.Monthly(datetime.Day,datetime.Hour); 

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IService>( recurringId, x =>x.CreateRecurring(id), cron);
```

How can I end this Recurring Job after 'n' times executing it?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this could be to pass in a specific number of times when the method that is called and prevent it from being executed once that number has been reached:

```
public class MyService : IService
{
    public int runCount = 0;

    public void CreateRecurring(id, int? maxTimes = null)
    {
        if (maxTimes.HasValue && (runCount >= maxTimes))
        {
            // Has run enough times now, don't do it again
            return;
        }

        // do something...
    }
}


// Run a max of 5 times
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IService>( recurringId, x =>x.CreateRecurring(id, 5), cron);
```